# Make Python wait until to_sql has finished

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-to-sql

I'm using to_sql to export my dataframe into a SQL Server table however I want to delay the execution of the next line of python code until the insertion has been completed.

I have a OKish understanding of database connections but I'm a bit of a noob when trying to understand how python and sql server communicate.

```
engine = db.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://username:password@ServerName/Database?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

df.to_sql('Table', engine, schema = 'dbo', if_exists='append',index=False)

#Don't execute this until all the records have been added
print("All my records have been added to SQL")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Python executes line by line. So it should not move on untill the `df.to_sql` line has finished.

Comment: It immediately prints the message as soon as to_sql has been executed even though the insert hasn't finished. I have tested this by triggering a SQL query immediately afterwards to capture the inserted records which returns nothing

Comment: I write to an ms sql daily, it definitely executes line by line. Are you sure you're connected to the right dB?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working as wasn't using autocommit = true

Comment: hi, I need to do something similar, do you mind showing where you have to put in autocommit? thanks @Big_Daz

Comment: Hi, luckily I save all my code for future use so this is how I solved it:             
#Start of the process to export the result back into SQL
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import event

#SQL Connection string
engine = db.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://**USERNAME**:**PASSWORD**@**SERVER NAME/**DATABSE**?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

Comment: #Export the data to the table
finaldf.to_sql('**TABLE NAME**', engine, schema = 'dbo', if_exists='append',index=False)

Comment: so no need for the autocommit then? ill try this out thanks!